# Write a function that takes as input `n` and returns the matrix C, Cij= 0 if i/j<2 , Cij =ij^2 otherwise in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

Consider the `n`x`n`  matrix `C` with elements

```
Cij = 0      if i/j < 2
Cij = ij^2   otherwise
             with 1 <= i,j <= n
```

Write a Matlab function `matSetup` that takes as input `n` and returns the matrix `C`. Use your function to create `C` for `n = 6`. `function [Cij]= matSetup(n)`

I have written this but it seems not to be correct

```
function Cij=matSetup(n)
for n=1:n
   % whatever you write here is done with i=1, then i=2, then i=3, etc.

Cij(3,j)=i+7;
if (i/j)<2
   Cij=0
else
    Cij=i*(j)^2

end
end
end
```

Comment: I suggest you start with the basics, for example taking a tutorial here: https://matlabacademy.mathworks.com

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't just write something math-like and have a computer understand it.  Things like `1<=i<=n` have to be written instead with something like an explicit loop.  For Matlab, here's one way to write a loop:

```
for i=1:n
   % whatever you write here is done with i=1, then i=2, then i=3, etc.
end
```

To assign a value to an element of an array in Matlab, do something like this:

```
Cij(3,j)=i+7;
```

To test for a condition in Matlab, do this:

```
if i+3>2*j
  % What you write here is done if the condition is true
else
  % What you write here is done if the condition is false
end
```

If you put all of those things together correctly, you should be able to write your desired function.

Comment: where did you find the numbers 2 and 3 ?

Comment: All the numbers and expressions here are just bits that I made up. You have to replace things as appropriate for your problem.

Comment: i have edited it, Could you tell me some corrections i have to do?

Comment: You probably need to back up to a more basic level. Try the tutorial that @CrisLuengo mentioned above.

Comment: Could you tell me what i have to change please?

Comment: Sorry, Stack Overflow can't do your homework. You need to learn the appropriate concepts so that you can do it yourself. If the tutorial linked above is too confusing, maybe you can find some other students or teachers locally who can help you get started. Trying to go back and forth online is impractical, and just giving you the answer helps no one.

Answer (score 0):

Like the other answer, you should first learn to use loops to write a naive program to achieve your goal. When you are comfortable enough, you can try vectorizing your program with functions like `meshgrid`. Below is an example:

```
n = 20;
eps = 1/(n+1);
[x, y] = meshgrid(1:n, 1:n);
r = y./x;
z = heaviside(r - 2 + eps) .* y .* x.^2;
```

Comment: I have edited my code, could you tell me what's wrong? Also i can not use meshgrid sorry,